# mysql: update a table's primary key which is referred by another table as foreign key

Tags: mysql

This is my DB structure

```
CREATE DATABASE Library;

CREATE TABLE Library.Book (
    ID        char(8),
    name      varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    author    varchar(10),
    price     float,
    status     int DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CHECK ( status >= 0 and status <= 1 ),
    CHECK ( price >= 0 )
);

CREATE TABLE Library.Reader (
    ID        char(8),
    name      varchar(10),
    age       int,
    address   varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Library.Borrow (
    Book_ID      char(8),
    Reader_ID    char(8),
    Borrow_Date  date,
    Return_Date  date,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Book_ID FOREIGN KEY (Book_ID) REFERENCES Library.Book(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Reader_ID FOREIGN KEY (Reader_ID) REFERENCES Library.Reader(ID)
);
```

and I write a store procedure as below

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Library.ChangeBookID (IN OriginID char(8), IN ModifiedID char(8))
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION #处理异常
        SET @STATUS = 1;
    CREATE TABLE Library.book_copy
    SELECT ID
    FROM Library.Book;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE Library.book_copy
        SET Library.book_copy.ID = ModifiedID
        WHERE Library.book_copy.ID = OriginID;
    if @STATUS = 0 THEN   #status = 0 means no transaction
        ALTER TABLE Library.Borrow
        DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_Book_ID;

        UPDATE Library.Borrow
            SET Library.Borrow.Book_ID = ModifiedID
            WHERE Library.Borrow.Book_ID = OriginID;

        DROP TABLE Library.Book;
        RENAME TABLE Library.Book_copy TO Library.Book;

        ALTER TABLE Library.Borrow
        ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Book_ID FOREIGN KEY (Book_ID) REFERENCES Library.Book(ID);
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK ;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

What I want is that if the modified primary key value is conflicted with the rest of this table, the procedure will rollback, else it will commit the changes. However, it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: Why are you changing the primary key in the first place?

Comment: It's also worth noting that these field lengths are comically small. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default for "string" type fields. Only constrain or extend if you have a specific reason.

Comment: Are you trying to implement something equivalent to `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in the foreign key?

Comment: If you want to know if `ModifiedID` conflicts, just do `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Library.book WHERE ID = ModifiedID)`

Comment: Yes, but my teacher said not all databases support ```ON UPDATE CASCADE```, so I try to copy the ```ID``` column  and then check whether it can be changed or not. If the ```ID``` value can be changed, I drop the foreign key first and change the ```ID``` value and then set the foreign key referrence again.

Comment: OK, I'll try ```IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Library.book WHERE ID = ModifiedID)```, I guess this can work!

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know why the store procedure I wrote before goes wrong, but with Barmar's help, I get another way which is much cleaner to solve this question.
Now, the new store procedure is as below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Library.ChangeBookID (IN OriginID char(8), IN ModifiedID char(8))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Library.book WHERE ID = ModifiedID) THEN
        ALTER TABLE Library.Borrow
        DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_Book_ID;

        UPDATE Library.Book
            SET Library.Book.ID = ModifiedID
        WHERE Library.Book.ID = OriginID;

        UPDATE Library.Borrow
            SET Library.Borrow.Book_ID = ModifiedID
        WHERE Library.Borrow.Book_ID = OriginID;

        ALTER TABLE Library.Borrow
        ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Book_ID FOREIGN KEY (Book_ID) REFERENCES Library.Book(ID);

        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Thank Barmar again and also thx4 tadman's help.